# None of the FedEx shipping methods except GROUND shows up in the frontend

Tags: magento2.4, fedex

The problem is that in the checkout page only FedEx GROUND method appears despite choosing GROUND, 2 Day and Home Delivery methods under Delivery methods in Magento admin. I wonder why other two don't show up.

Comment: Please check product assign the weight ?

Comment: Checked, still no luck.

Comment: The shipping log shows 'Message' => 'Authentication Failed',

Comment: You have to check FEDEX credentials.

Comment: This worked with the production credentials. The problem is that in the checkout page only GROUND method appears despite choosing GROUND, 2 Day and Home Delivery.